# Social Security Disability to Social Security

Tags: united-states, social-security

I am currently 62 1/2 yrs. old on SSDI and want to return to work. Can I apply for regular Social Security and return to work and not have to worry about losing my income.

Comment: Perhaps asking your local Social Security office might be better than relying on opinions here.

Answer (score 3):

I, also, am on SSDI. I am also 63 Yrs old.

SSDI has a return to work program that allows you to earn income while you still get SSDI checks. It has a time limit you can do this which is a year, if I remember correctly.

Also, you can work part time and not put your SSDI at risk if you earn less than a certain amount each month. Last time I checked (about three years ago) the limit was $1000 a month. I believe that you have to report your income to the SS office each month.

But to get definitive answers you need to visit your SS office.